# Xamarin: is it possible to click items in BoxView and "go" to next page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have a side menu in my app that shows up when you swipe left. The side menu is basically a BoxView that contains a list of Menu items such as **Settings** and **Login**.

My question is: **Is it possible to click on a specific item in the BoxView? For example Settings.**

***I have tried*** to make the items clickable through creating methods in MainPage.cs. Did not really work.

Here is some code in case you need it.

**MainPage.cs:**

```
       private List<Menu> GetMenus()
            {
                return new List<Menu>
                {
                    new Menu { Title = "Home", Type = ButtonType.Home, Icon = "Icon.Images.icon.png"},
                    new Menu { Title = "Settings", Type = ButtonType.Settings, Icon = "Icon.Images.icon.png"},
                    new Menu { Title = "Rotate", Type = ButtonType.Rotate, Icon = "Icon.Images.icon.png"},
                };
    
            }


 private void OpenSwipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CloseSwipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

The result I am getting now is that every time I click on a menu item, the side menu closes again.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
  <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <!--<Image Aspect="Fill" Source="icon.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Image>-->
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" Opacity="0.9">


        </BoxView>
        <SwipeView x:Name="MainSwipeView" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <SwipeItems>
                    <SwipeItemView>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="35" WidthRequest="100" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyMenu}"
                                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="CloseSwipe">
                                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <pancakeView:PancakeView  HeightRequest="30"
                                                                     WidthRequest="30" CornerRadius="15" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                                     HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                                <ImageButton Source="{Binding icon.png}" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"></ImageButton>
                                            </pancakeView:PancakeView>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </Grid>
                    </SwipeItemView>
                </SwipeItems>
            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
            <Grid x:Name="swipeContent">
                <pancakeView:PancakeView x:Name="WebView1"  Background="Gray">
                    <Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Padding="30">
                                <Image Source="{iconWareApp:ImageResource iconWareApp.Images.icon.png}" HeightRequest="18" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OpenSwipe" ></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>

                                <ImageButton Source="{iconWareApp:ImageResource iconWareApp.Images.icon.png}" HeightRequest="36" HorizontalOptions="End" ></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                                <views:HybridWebView x:Name="WebView" />

                            </Grid>
                            <views:MenuView HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"></views:MenuView>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </pancakeView:PancakeView>
            </Grid>
        </SwipeView>
    </Grid>
```

**UPDATED:**

What I mean is that I have a side menu and in it there are 3 menu items, in this case I would like to go into the Settings. (AND I USE BOXVIEW TO CHANGE THE COLOR OF THE SIDE MENU)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Ub2.png)

Have a look at the image. These items (Home, Settings, Home) suppose to take me to other pages, but they don't do that. That is my problem.

Comment: the only BoxView I see in your code is empty, so I'm not sure what relevance that has?

Comment: yes it is empty, and i dont know if i should fill it.. well i am quite new with xamarn forms... @Jason

Comment: I don't know what you expect us to tell you.  Yes, it is possible to click on an item in a BoxView (using a GestureRecognizer) but that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you posted.

Comment: You just told me what I needed to know :D @Jason could you possibly give me an example?

Comment: An example of what?  You are already using a GestureRecognizer so I assume you know how that works.

Comment: Well, an example of an item that is clickable in boxview? In my case I cannot click the items I have in the boxview,

Comment: your BoxView is empty, as I pointed out in the first comment

Comment: @Jason I have updated my question, please have a look when you have time.

Comment: The purpose of using BoxView is to change the side menu background color? Why not create the project by using template "Flyout"? You only need to modifty the AppShell FlyoutBackgroundColor.